# Regex no numbers and one space between words

Tags: regex, xml

I'm working on a regex for xml and I'm stumped. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?  I'm trying to validate a city name where I can have lower and upper case letters and all special characters, as well as a white space between words, no space at the beginning or after the last word.  No numbers allowed.  I've researched and can't seem to make any headway.  Here's what I have so far, any help is greatly appreciated:

```
^[a-zA-Z\s.\-_|\/\\@#~=%,;?!'"`():$+*\^\[\]&amp;&lt;&gt;{}]*$
```

Comment: Is it for an XSD schema?

Comment: it is for a stinger.xml and I tested all the below suggestions and they are not working for me.

Comment: That is because your question is unclear. State the regex flavor, provide sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

it's easier to specify the complement set

```
/^[^0-9 ][^0-9]+[^0-9 ]$/
```

starts and ends with non space or non digit, shouldn't include digits in between.  Note that this requires at least 3 chars as minimum length.  You can tailor it pass one chars but will complicate the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negated character sets `[^ <characters> ]` to disallow numbers and leading/trailing spaces like this:

```
^(?:(?! )[^0-9]*[^ 0-9])?$
```

**Breakdown:**

- Match an optional group:

  - Assert that the first character is not a space;
  - Match any number of non-digits;
  - Match a single non-digit that is also not a space.

**Demo (JavaScript):**

```js
var re = /^(?:(?! )[^0-9]*[^ 0-9])?$/

console.log(re.test(' ')) //=> false
console.log(re.test(' city ')) //=> false
console.log(re.test('city name')) //=> true
console.log(re.test('')) //=> true (if this is undesirable behavior, let me know)
console.log(re.test(' c')) //=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex expression, as said by others, using the complement set which matches anything except the specified things.
This will work with string of length 1 or more,  you will catch an extra group but you can just ignore it:

```
^[^\d\s]([^\d]*[^\d\s])?$/m
```

#### Explanation :

- `^[^\d\s]` makes sure the string starts with something that doesn't match a number or any kind of space.
- `([^\d]*[^\d\s])?$` this makes sure that the string ends with something not a digit or any kind of space, also using `?` to make sure strings of length ` are matched!